# C++ returning by value

Tags: c++, function, copy-constructor

From the code below below I was expecting for class CA that the following would be called

1. constructor creating the temporary object to be returned by the function `foo`
2. copy constructor to create the variable to be passed to the variable `a` in the main
3. another copy constructor that would create the `a` variable from the value returned by the function.

Why it is not the case? The result I have is just

```
A
```

While I was expecting

```
ABB
```

So only the constructor is called. Is compiler optimizing something behind the scenes or have I missed some C++ concept?

```
class CA{
public:
   CA(){ std::cout << "A"; }
   CA( const CA& ){ std::cout << "B"; }
   CA& operator=(const CA& ){ std::cout << "C";return *this; }
};

CA foo(){
      return CA();
}

int main(){
 CA a = foo();    
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is compiler optimizing something behind the scenes or I missed some C++ concept?

Spot on! It's called copy elision. Look up RVO and NRVO on google. You should also look up the rule of three.

Copy elision is the only optimization the compiler is allowed to perform that affects observable behavior. You shouldn't place important logic in the copy constructor for that reason.

Comment: If you think about it - the ctor is the only thing that HAS to run

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two "kinds" of optimizations in C++.

- First kind are specific optimizations explicitly introduced by the language specification.
- Second kind is all those wild and unpredictable optimizations that compiler do under the "as-if" rule (i.e. the compiler can do absolutely anything as long as observable behavior of the program remains unchanged).

(Some might say that only the second kind of optimizations are *true* optimizations.)

What you see here is an optimization of the first kind. When performing multi-step copying operations, the language specification explicitly always allowed the compilers to eliminate intermediate temporary copies.

Moreover, the C++03 and later versions of the language specification take it one step further: they explicitly permit the compilers to perform the "Named Return Value Optimization" (NRVO), which actually eliminates a named (non-temporary) object.

Both reduce the number of copy operations in the program.

Such copy elimination optimizations in C++ are allowed even if they change the observable behavior of the program, i.e. the optimizations of the first kind can sometimes violate the restrictions imposed on the second kind. In your case, even though you inserted I/O operations into the copy constructor, the compiler is still permitted to eliminate the invocations of that constructor.

The code that you posted does not require NRVO. A good C++98 compiler should be able to produce the result you observed. If you want to see whether your compiler does NRVO in such cases, you might want to try this

```
CA foo(){
  Ca ca;
  return ca;
}
```